# Make a database table read only temporarily (and not raising errors)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

In our software we have something like a cache inside a table of a database hosted on a Microsoft SQL-Server (2008 R2 to 2019).
Now I have to debug some lines of code which only run, when this cache is empty. Otherwise the data comes from the cache and the code I need to debug doesn't run.

Since I'm sick of always manually deleting the content of this cache table before I can debug again, I'm looking for a way to make this cache table read-only for a while.

I can't change the code which is actually writing data to this cache table, so I'm looking for a way to achieve my goal with only using the SQL Management Studio, preferably running a TSQL script to switch on the read-only-ability and another script to switch it off again.

Googling for that I found several ways to accomplish that, but unfortunately all the ways I googled raise an error, which prevents our software to run along.

My preferred solution would be a trigger on my cache table, something like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER CacheNoInsert ON CacheTable
INSTEAD OF INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE
AS
BEGIN
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
END
```

But this trigger is raising an error. And removing the `ROLLBACK TRANSACTION` results in a syntax error.

So, is there any way to change this trigger to not raise an error? Or is there any other way to achieve my goal without errors?

Comment: What langue are you debugging? In Visual Studio you can drag/drop the yellow debug cursor to a different line. Skipping parts of the code like `if (/**/)`

Comment: The code which is actually writing data to the cache table is in a completely different and independent assembly, and I do not have the source code of that assembly so I cannot skip any lines of code in there. But if it is of any concern I'm trying to debug VB.NET/C# code.

Comment: If you load the PDB you can still debug an external assembly

Comment: I don't have the PDB either, I only have the release-compiled version of that assembly. And I don't want to skip one line of code a thousand times. If that would be the solution then it's more convenient do manually empty the cache table once before each debug run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I think I found a solution. Removing the `ROLLBACK TRANSACTION` and putting a non-sense line of code between `BEGIN` and `END` did the trick.

```
CREATE TRIGGER CacheNoInsert ON CacheTable
INSTEAD OF INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE
AS
BEGIN
    PRINT 'doesntMatter'
END
```

But I hope the transaction will still be removed either by committing or by rolling back.